# how to extract specific value from a configmap using oc client

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, openshift

My config map looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  my-data.yaml |2-
   #data comes here
kind: ConfigMap
```

Is it possible to extract the content of `my-data.yaml` key via

```
oc get configmap
```

or any other `oc` command?

e.g.

```
oc get configmap myconfigmap  -o=yaml <[only my-data.yaml]>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to demonstrate an example command, which "coderanger" mentioned before.

This example converted from yaml to json and filtered ".keyname" using "jq" command after that.
You can also use "yq" command instead of python one-liner and jq combination.

```
oc get configmap/myconfigmap \
   -o "jsonpath={ .data['my-data\.yaml']}" | \
   python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; y=yaml.load(sys.stdin.read()); print json.dumps(y)' | \
   jq '. | .keyname'
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: this is what I need, I think I don't even need the python part

Answer (score 1):

No. As far as kube sees, that’s just one long string. You could use the json path output mode to filter to just the one value though. And then parse it with jq or yq. Or just use jq twice :)

Comment: please elaborate json path part

Answer (score 1):

There are some shell workarounds to parse `yaml` files:

### `yq`

You may use `yq`, a command line YAML processor built on top of [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

You can download it and find documentation at http://mikefarah.github.io/yq/.

### `niet`

> Another tool is [openuado/niet](https://github.com/openuado/niet)
>
> Niet is like [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) or [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) but for YAML and JSON data - you can use it to slice and filter and map and transform structured data.
>
> You can easily retrieve data by using simple expressions or using xpath advanced features to access non-trivial data.
>
> You can easily convert YAML format into JSON format and vice versa.

### `bash-yaml` for pure `bash`

For pure `bash` you can try:

- either [jasperes/bash-yaml](https://github.com/jasperes/bash-yaml)
- or [mrbaseman/parse_yaml: a simple yaml parser implemented in bash](https://github.com/mrbaseman/parse_yaml)

#### `jasperes/bash-yaml`

> Read a yaml file and create variables in bash

Simple 41-lines-of-bash [script](https://github.com/jasperes/bash-yaml/blob/master/script/yaml.sh) uses only `sed` and `awk` to parse `yaml`-file and create variables from it.

#### `mrbaseman/parse_yaml`

> `parse_yaml` provides a bash function that allows parsing simple YAML files. The output is shell code that defines shell variables which contain the parsed values. `bash` doesn't support multidimensional arrays. Therefore a separate variable is created for each value, and the name of the variable consists of the names of all levels in the yaml file, glued together with a separator character which defaults to `_`

Answer (score 0):

(with OpenShift/OKD `oc` tool) you can `extract` data from a ConfigMaps or Secrets as files:

```
oc extract configmap/<myconfigmap> --key=<my-data.file1>,<my-data.fileN> -n my-namespace

oc extract secrete/<myconfigmap> --key=<my-data.file1>,<my-data.fileN> -n my-namespace
```

with the `--key` parameter it will extract the selected <my-data.file1>,<my-data.fileN> in your local directory

without the `--key` parameter it will extract all the files.